# Can't start client and server together with concurrently

Tags: node.js, reactjs, concurrently

index.js:
`const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`

server package.json:

```
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

client package.json:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

I am starting it with `npm run dev`

Any idea where the problem might be?

error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '.../index.js'
```

Comment: Let's see your folder structure? For now I'm gonna take a guess and tell you to try `../../index.js`

Comment: folder structure is: main folder: project and inside client folder (for react) and src folder (server) where the index.js resides

Comment: do you have the client or server in a subpath? if yes, you need to run "cd <path> &&" at comand definitions

Comment: what do you mean by subpath? I didn't quite understand what I need to do?

Comment: I'll write an aswer and you'll undersand, wait...

Comment: Tried it, still the same

Answer (score 1):

try to map the subpath of the client project:

```
{
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
```

Answer (score 0):

as I have had **application** and **server** folders, the same problems appeared. And I resolved it by giving the path
--> **"application": "cd ../ && npm start --prefix application"**

```
{
  "server": "nodemon server/app.js",
  "application": "cd ../ && npm start --prefix application",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run application\" "
}
```